# apache .htaccess: hiding subdomain redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have this problem: I want for example that http://www.mydomain.com/experiential/mypage will be redirected to http://subdomain.mydomain.com/mypage without showing the change in the address bar.
Physically, the domain and subdomain will be hosted on different servers.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried with

```
RewriteRule ^experiential/(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But the redirect shows in the acdress bar

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you enable mod_proxy on the Apache that is hosting `www.mydomain.com`. Once that is enabled have rules like this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^experiential/(.+?)/?$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [P,L,NC]
```